Which piece moved last?
After my last few retrograde chess puzzles were all a bit on the trickier side, this one should once again be a bit more approachable. Your task is simple:
Can you tell which piece made the last move?

Please provide your reasoning in your answer. Have fun! :)

When you say "piece", you're including pawns?

@msh210 Yes, pawns are included.

Is there only one possible answer?  In other words, does one need to make any assumptions about what moves a reasonable chess player would have made, or should one only consider what moves could have been made?

@RyanM There is only one logically possible answer (assuming that I did not mess the puzzle up, of course). This is not a puzzle about "strategic" (i.e. normal) chess - all that matters is that moves are legal :)

I can tell it's either RxNb7 or BxNa7. But in either case the released Knight cannot seem to do anything as there are not enough pieces to clear the double check... Hang on I have an idea

I really would like to see a game where the white king manages to get into this particular  position :-)

Solution
The piece that made the last move is

 the Bishop on a7, which captured a Knight.

A possible way to reach this position is
Bd4xNa7 Nb5-a7 Ba7-d4+ Nd6-b5 Kg8-h8 Ne4-d6 Kh8-g8 Nf6-e4 f3-f4 Ng8-f6 g5-g6 Ne6-f8 g4-g5 Rf8-e8 f2-f3 Re8-d8 Qd8-c8 Qc8-b8 Rb4-b7 Ng5-e6 Rf4-b4 Qb7-c8 Rf3-f4 Qb4-b7 Rg3-f3 Qd6-b4 Rg1-g3 Ne6-g5 Rh1-g1 Ng5-e6 Rb8-a8 Ne6-g5 Bd4-a7 Ng5-e6 Bb2-d4 Ne6-g5 Bc1-b2 Ng5-e6 b2-b3 Ne6-g5 Bd5-a2 Ba2-b1 Be4-d5 Bd5-a2 Nb3-a1 Ng5-e6 Nd4-b3 Ne6-g5 Rb3-b8 Ng5-e6 Ra3-b3 Ne6-g5 Ra1-a3 Ng5-e6 Qb8-d8 Ne6-g5 Qb3-b8 Ng5-e6 Qg3-b3 Ne6-g5 Qg1-g3 Ng5-e6 Qd1-g1 Ne6-g5 a2-a4 Kb6-a6 Nb5-d4 Ra8-e8 Na3-b5 Kc5-b6 Nb1-a3 Ra6-a8 Na3-b1 Rb6-a6 Nb1-a3 Rb3-b6 Na3-b1 Rh3-b3 Nb1-a3 Rh6-h3 Na3-b1 Rb8-f8 Nb1-a3 Rb3-b8 Na3-b1 Rh3-b3 Nb1-a3 Nf6-g8 Kg8-h8 Nh5-f6+ Kf8-g8 Ng5-e6+ Ke8-f8 Kd4-c5 Kd8-e8 Bc4-d5 Kc8-d8 Rg6-h6 Kb8-c8 Rh6-g6 Ka8-b8 Rb3-h3 Ka7-a8 Rb8-b3 Na3-b1 Rh8-b8 Kb7-a7 Re6-h6 Ka7-b7 Re5-e6 Kb7-a7 Rd5-e5 Nb1-a3 Nf6-h5 Kc8-b7 Ng8-f6+ Na3-b1 Rb5-d5 Nb1-a3 Rb6-b5 Na3-b1 Ra6-b6 Nb1-a3 Ra7-a6 Na3-b1 Ne6-g5 Nb1-a3 Nc5-e6 Na3-b1 Na6-c5 Nb1-a3 Nb8-a6 Na3-b1 Ra8-a7 Kb7-c8 a7-a5 Nb1-a3 Bd5-c4 Na3-b1 Na6-b8 Nb1-a3 Nb4-a6 Ka6-b7 Nd3-b4+ Ka5-a6 Kc5-d4 Ka4-a5 Kb6-c5 Kb4-a4 Nc5-d3+ Kc3-b4 Kb7-b6 Kd3-c3 Na6-c5+ Ke3-d3 Kc8-b7 Kf3-e3 Kd8-c8 Kg2-f3 Ke8-d8 Kf1-g2 Qc5-d6 Ke1-f1 Qb6-c5 Bg2-e4 Qb8-b6 Bf1-g2 Qd8-b8 Na3-b1 Nb8-a6 Nb1-a3 Bc4-d5 Na3-b1 Ba6-c4 Nb1-a3 Bb7-a6 Na3-b1 Bc8-b7 Nb1-a3 b7xNc6 Nd4-c6 Nh6-g8 Ne6-d4 Nf5-h6 Nf8-e6 Nh6-f5 Ne6xBf8 Ng8-h6 Ng5-e6 Nf6-g8 Nf3-g5 Ng8-f6 Ng1-f3 Nf6-g8 g3-g4 Ng8-f6 g2-g3

I suggest that you paste the FEN RqQrrn1K/BRpppppp/k1p3P1/p7/P4P2/1P6/B1PPP2P/Nb6 along with the solution into Retractor 2 (on a computer browser) to follow along.
Instructions:

in top left "Mode" select Edit
paste FEN into the textbox under the chessboard
click "Set"
in top left "Retract next" select White
in top left "Mode" select Play
under chessboard, click "Paste", then paste solution
use arrows under chessboard to navigate

Reasoning

First we determine the missing pieces

Black's f8 Bishop died on its origin square
b7xc6 captured a White Knight
a Black Knight was captured


Black doesn't have any moves to retract, so White must retract and un-capture the Black Knight. The only possible capturers are Ba7 and Rb8.
To maximise White's moves, the retractions by the White Pawns are as follows:

b3 pawn cannot retract yet
a4 pawn cannot retract yet to allow the Black King use of b5 because either the White Rook a1 or Bishop c1 will end up locked out.
f4 pawn back to f2 (2 moves)
g6 pawn back to g4 (2 moves)


Due to the the double check on the Black King by the Rook, one of the following recent histories is forced.

Bishop takes Knight: B??xNa7 Nb5-a7 Ba7-??+ (discovered check)
Rook takes Knight: R??xNb7 N(c5 or d6)-b7 Rb7-??+ (discovered check)


We know that Knights cannot waste exactly one tempo while the White King also cannot waste a tempo being constrained in the top right. (A "parity" constraint)
We want the un-captured Knight to get to g8 to unlock f8, e8, d8, and eventually c8 and b7 to give White moves to retract and essentially unlocking the position.
The 4 White Pawn retractions will be used up just before the following moves: Ng8-??, N??-f8, Rf8-e8, Re8-d8. So they cannot be used to otherwise waste tempo.
Let M(x) be the number of Knight moves from square x to g8, then

M(a7) = 5 (or a larger odd number),
M(b7) = 4 (or a larger even number).


The Knight must arrive on c6 or a6 after an even number of White King moves to avoid an impossible check.

The Knight moves 2 times before White King starts retracting, and c6 or a6 is 1 move from g8. So if x is the death-square of the Knight then M(x) = 2 + 1 + even = odd.
So x = a7 is the only possibility.



Complications

My proof game is inordinately long (almost 200 moves, unoptimised) since pieces of both colours have to be retracted along the same narrow exit.
After getting the White King to the a-file, start retracting in the following order:

h8 Rook
a8 Rook (use Knights to block the checks)
a2 pawn (this lets the White King out without shutting out the c8 Bishop
get White King out
Black King, Black Queen, c8 Bishop
un-capture the White Knight
un-capture the f8 Bishop
use the g4 pawn to resolve any parity issues



Comments

It's been a while since I've seen the parity constraint come into play. What a fun puzzle!


You figured it out! Well done :)

Grossly incomplete answer (I misread the question; having had this kindly pointed out in comments I spent a short while seeing whether I could finish the job before needing to go to bed tonight, but it turns out I can't. I'll leave this here because I don't believe in hiding my mistakes, though in the very likely event that someone else posts an actually-correct answer before I get back to this -- I'm spending most of tomorrow travelling -- I will probably delete it.)
Let's suppose that

 black

made the last move, and ask: what might it have been?

 None of the pawns, nor the pieces other than K and N, have any empty squares they can possibly just have moved from. If the last move was with the N then it must have been a capture (since otherwise the WK was in check before that move), but W has only had one piece captured (a knight) and that was obviously on c6. So if black moved last it was with the king.

But

 the BK can only have moved from b6 or b5. If b6 (in check from the WBa7 and the WRb7) then there is no square for the WB on a7 to have moved from to deliver check. If b5 (in check from the WPa4 and the WRb7) there is no possible last white move to have established both of those checks. (The only way to put a K in check with a P is to move that P; no possible move by that P could have created the check from the WRb7.)

So

 there are no possible last black moves, and the last move was white's.

I suspect I may be missing something because

 there are lots of other things discoverable about this position, none of which I have used at all here.


Which piece moved last, not just which player.

Ah, I can't read. Duh. Thank you.
